# How to remove WordPress margin-top: 0 !important in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a billboard banner on the very top of my website but it won't appear as there is some CSS: `margin-top: 0 !important`. However I cannot find where that line in the CSS is. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried overwriting the styling with another `!important` styling?

Comment: No and I am unsure how to do that. I also do not know where the original styling is.